# Counter Cache Behavior When Not Saving a Has Many / Belongs To Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given the following models and schema:

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "comments_count", default: 0, null: false
end

create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "post_id"
end

class Post
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :post, counter_cache: true
end
```

Running the following snippet produces some strange behaviour:

```
post = Post.create
post.comments_count # 0
post.comments.count # 0

comment = Comment.create
5.times do 
  comment.reload
  comment.post = post # NOTE: not saved but executes UDPATE for counter cache
end

post.reload
post.comments_count # 5
post.comments.count # 0
```

Any way to fix so that the counter cache is only modified (preferably within a transaction) when the foreign key is actually modified?

**Logs**:

```
Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY "posts"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
SQL (6.2ms)  UPDATE "posts" SET "comments_count" = COALESCE("comments_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "posts"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]
```

Comment: Did you declare `counter_cache: true` on your belongs_to relation?

Comment: @mysmallidea yes - sorry typo in original question - counter caches are working fine outside of this sample

Comment: That's weird - it shouldn't even commit to the db based on your code snippet. Can you post your logs for each of the operations?

Comment: This appears to be a bug that may or may not still exist:  
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13304  
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/14849

Comment: @mysmallidea I added the log output (that would show up five times - the initial call does the reload then the subsequent calls change the count.

Comment: @Eric that was my initial guess. Tested on a few versions of Rails (4.x and 5.x) - had this unexpected behaviour in all. I've always noticed counter caches drift towards inaccuracy - probably better to proxy via a view / stats model.

Comment: You can absolutely write something to maintain them manually, it's not a big deal, but you can also use `ActiveRecord::Base#reset_counters` if you think they're drifting.